# how to insert filled text area only from the input form?

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
<form action='newEmptyPHP.php' method='post'>
    <p><input type='text' name='Name' placeholder='Customer Name' /></p>
    <p><input type='text' name='Phone' placeholder='phone Number' /></p>
    <p><input type='text' name='aphone' placeholder='Alternative phone Number' /></p>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Add'><br>
</form>
```

and the query

```
INSERT INTO `cus`(name,phone)
   VALUES ('$usernam',$phone),('$usernam',$aphone)"
```

but i want to add the $aphone if there is alternative phone number, if there is no alternative phone number how can i make my sql to insert only the main phone number only??? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show your query to insert into table

Comment: it's a matter of using conditional statements http://php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php

Comment: plus, better make sure that phone's an integer

Comment: what about 555-444-333 format, or +(23) 42424 -2 32 - 2 22?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the content of the variables. If `$aphone` are empty you dont execute the sql because the user dont enter a alternative phone number. To check the variables you can use the function [empty](http://php.net/manual/de/function.empty.php).

Try this:

```
if(!empty($aphone)) {
$sql = "INSERT INTO `cus`(name,phone)
        VALUES ('".$usernam."','".$aphone."')";
} 
if(!empty($phone)) {
$sql = "INSERT INTO `cus`(name,phone)
        VALUES ('".$usernam."','".$phone."')";
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i have add a explanation.

Comment: when i fill the first field it works fine but when i fill both of the phone fields it only stores the first field value on database.

Comment: What does `echo $aphone` says?

Comment: where can i check that ??

Comment: Before the if statement you can add the line `var_dump($aphone);` Execute the script and look in your browser.

Comment: ohhh i get it!! it was my problem with input field name and $_post name didnt match.. thats y it aint insert the last value!!

Answer (score 0):

On newEmptyPHP.php page add following code:

```
$aphone=$_POST["aphone"];

$phone=$_POST["Phone"];

$usernam=$_POST["Name"];

if( $aphone )
{

  mysql_query(con,"INSERT INTO `cus`(name,phone) VALUES ('$usernam',$aphone)");  

}

mysql_query(con,"INSERT INTO `cus`(name,phone) VALUES ('$usernam',$phone)");
```